# angular.forEach looping through string array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that checks for userPermissions and it is part of a Service called MyService . I am passing in an array with only one string. The issue I am facing is angular.forEach is looping through character by character instead of the complete string. Please can you advise?

**//Service changes**

```
MyService.userHasPermission("['Read']")
```

**//Permission function**

```
 function userHasPermission (permissions){
        var found = false;
        angular.forEach(permissions, function(expectedPermission, index){
            if ($localStorage.userPermissions.indexOf(expectedPermission) >= 0){
                found = true;
                return;
            }
        });

        return found;
    };
```

Comment: You are passing a **string** and not an array

Comment: You need to pass array. Not a string

Comment: Exactly. You need to do `MyService.userHasPermission(['Read'])`

Comment: oh! I get it now, thanks a lot guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`"abcde".forEach()` will loop through every letter. That's how forEach works. `"['Read']".forEach()` will just go through [,',R,e,a,d,',].

`MyService.userHasPermission(['Read'])` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in array instead of string.
Use **MyService.userHasPermission(['Read'])** instead of **MyService.userHasPermission("['Read']")**. 
*angular.forEach* takes in array as first parameter which in your case is character array so you will either need to pass in array of strings for your code to work as expected.